# Logo getting distorted in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, heroku

I have recently deployed an app on Heroku. In this app, an image should be shown on hover. I have checked the website on Safari and on Chrome. Turns out the image shows up fine on Safari but looks distorted on Chrome. 
I am assuming Chrome is causing the issue but I don't understand why.
Question 1: Is it really because of Chrome?
Question 2: How to fix it?

Another image used for similar purpose works on hover. It is in PNG format file, much like the other image.

I have attached the links of image seen in Safari and Chrome.

[Safari]- https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRQlD.jpg
[Chrome]- https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMNFL.jpg

Comment: Try compressing the PNG and reuploading it - http://compresspng.com/

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks!

Comment: great, I have submitted a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be most likely a rendering issue caused by whatever application you used to save. Compressing the image or resaving could solve the problem. [compresspng.com](http://compresspng.com). fix the rendering and reduce the file size, it's a win-win situation!